# Add multiString registry value using WiX?

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

Now I use something like this:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="<guid>" KeyPath="yes">  
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="<path>" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">  
    <RegistryValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
      1  
    </RegistryValue>  
    <RegistryValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
      2
    </RegistryValue>  
    <RegistryValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
      3
    </RegistryValue>  
    <RegistryValue Name="myString" Value="x" Type="string"/>  
  </RegistryKey>  
</Component>
```

But I have the next error:

The primary key `"reg<key>"` is duplicated in table 'Registry'. Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.

**ANSWER**: After [Yan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749863/how-to-add-multistring-registry-value-using-wix/3750829#3750829) answer my xml looks like:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="<guid>">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="<path>" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
    <RegistryValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">
      <MultiStringValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
        1
      </MultiStringValue>
      <MultiStringValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
        2
      </MultiStringValue>
      <MultiStringValue Name="myStrings" Action="append" Type="multiString">  
        3
      </MultiStringValue>
    </RegistryValue>
    <RegistryValue Name="myString" Value="x" Type="string"/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Comment: ohhh, so cumbersome!! finally found working solution! I was not able to realize how to use multistring.

Comment: Actually, all the attributes of MultiStringValue tags have no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [MultiStringValue](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_multistringvalue.htm) element.

Answer (score 8):

Actually all it needs to be is this:

```
<RegistryValue Type="multiString" Name="Value Name">
  <MultiStringValue>1</MultiStringValue>
  <MultiStringValue>2 &lt; 3</MultiStringValue>   <!-- Stands for 2 < 3 -->
  <MultiStringValue>33</MultiStringValue>
</RegistryValue>
```