# WiX MultiString registry keys

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer, wix2

I tried adding registry keys for compatibility assistant to a wix setup like this:

```
<File Id="File1.exe" Name="File1.exe" LongName="File1.exe" Source="..\Binaries\File1.exe" DiskId="1" />
<File Id="File2.exe" Name="File2.exe" LongName="File2.exe" Source="..\Binaries\File2.exe" DiskId="1" />
<File Id="File3.exe" Name="File3.exe" LongName="File3.exe" Source="..\Binaries\File3.exe" DiskId="1" />
<Registry Root="HKLM"
          Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant"
          Name="ExecutablesToExclude"
          Type="multiString"
          Action="append">
    <RegistryValue Action="append" Value="[File1.exe]" />
    <RegistryValue Action="append" Value="[File2.exe]" />
    <RegistryValue Action="append" Value="[File3.exe]" />
</Registry>
```

But when installing no key gets generated. Am I missing anything or doing something wrong? I got the details for what I'm doing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749863/how-to-add-multistring-registry-value-using-wix) and the wix documentation.

Update:
The syntax is a bit different, I think because the question I pointed to uses a different version of WiX. The syntax I used is the only one WiX 2 accepts, and this wix file builds fine - it just doesn't generate new registry entries.

---

Update: I was misdiagnosing the problem; the wix scrpit worked properly, but put the values in the `Wow6432bit` node of the registry because the containing component didn't have the attribute `Win64="yes"`.

Comment: In the question you are pointing to, `<MultiStringValue>` is used. Is there any reason you are doing it differently?

Comment: @Wimmel: I think it's because it's a different version of WiX. I've updated the question to mention that.

Comment: Great it's resolved! I would never guess this based on the initial info you provided... :)

Comment: @Yan: Me neither... Somebody else in the office spotted it by chance :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, [RegistryValue](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registryvalue.htm) element in WiX2 doesn't have attributes. I wonder, how your sample gets compiled without errors...

Anyway, try to rewrite your Registry element like this:

```
<Registry Root="HKLM"
          Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant"
          Name="ExecutablesToExclude"
          Type="multiString"
          Action="append">
    <RegistryValue>[File1.exe]</RegistryValue>
    <RegistryValue>[File2.exe]</RegistryValue>
    <RegistryValue>[File3.exe]</RegistryValue>
</Registry>
```

Comment: I just tried that and I get exactly the same effect - the setup doesn't even create the multistring key.